# MJPG IP Camera Feed Displays in Firefox But Not Other Browsers

Tags: html, image, ip-camera, mjpeg

The below URL works from within an html file on Firefox but not Chrome, Brave or Edge browsers.  Has been tested on Linux/Firefox, Windows/Firefox, Windows/Chrome, Windows/Edge, Android/Firefox and Android/Brave.  Browsers not working seem to ignore the URL from within an html file and do not display an image (alt= is used instead), but pasting the URL directly into the address bar does surface an image.  What am I missing?

http://id:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1

Code within file that works in Firefox:

```
<img
  src="http://id:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1" 
  width="512" 
  alt='mjpg video feed'
/>
```